# How to attach External Material in Schoology (LMS) assignment using API

Tags: mass-assignment, external-tools, schoology

We are using **Schoology API** to create Assignments as mentioned in API documentation (https://developers.schoology.com/api-documentation/rest-api-v1/assignment/)

We want to add third party Links **(LinkAttachments)** using **external tool** through REST **API**. As per API documentation there is no field for external tool attachment.

We have tried the following POST to add the external material:

```
array("title" => $post['name'],
      "description" => $post['description'],
      "due" => "2024-03-19 11:30:00",
      "type" => "assignment",
      "assignees" => [],
      "grading_group_ids" => [],
      "count_in_grade" => 0,
      "external_tools" => [
           "et-1" => [
               "tp_nid" => "6817019218",
               "title" => "Test CN",
               "url" => "http://local.magicedtech.com/slooh/login.php",
               "consumer_key" => "",
               "shared_secret" => "",
               "custom_parameters" => "cust=123"
                ],
           ]
        );
```

So, we required the solution to add external material in Schoology Assignments.

Our expectation to add assignment with external tool attachment using REST API(s).